# WatchOS: Bluetooth CBCentralManager is always in 'unsupported' state on stand-alone Apple Watch app

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, apple-watch, watchos-6

As a little experiment I am trying to build a stand-alone WatchOS 6+ app with Bluetooth interaction. I start with a simple code which I use many times:

```
final class MyBluetoothInterface: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate { 
    private var _centralManager: CBCentralManager!

    override init() {
        self._centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: nil, queue: nil)
        super.init()
        self._centralManager.delegate = self
    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        scanServices(central)
    }

    func scanServices(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        print("Central is not powered on! It's in '\(central.state)' state.")
        guard central.state == .poweredOn else { return }
        central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
    }

}
```

But CBCentralManager is always 'unsupported'. According to Apple's doc 'unsupported' state means that the device doesn't support BLE. I am using Apple Watch Series 1 + WatchOS 6.1. And as I know Series 1 supports BLE.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue but on a MacBook Air. I checked the system report, and the laptop does support BLE, but the `CBCentralManager` state is always `.unsupported`.